# Why Python keeps telling me missing positional argument even the parameter already has the positional argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

I am a Python-3 novice with limited experiences.
Could someone answer me: Why Python keeps telling me my code is missing a positional argument even the parameter already has the positional argument?
Here is my code

```
    """A simple attempt to represent a car."""

    def __init__(self, manufacturer, model, year):
        """Initialize attributes to describe a car."""
        self.manufacturer = manufacturer
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0
        self.miles=0

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        """Return a neatly formatted descriptive name."""
        long_name = str(self.year) + ' ' + self.manufacturer + ' ' + self.model
        return long_name.title()

    def read_odometer(self):
        """Print a statement showing the car's mileage."""
        return("This car now has " + str(self.odometer_reading) + " miles on it.")

    def update_odometer(self, mileage):

        if mileage >= self.odometer_reading:
            self.odometer_reading = mileage
        else:
            print("You can't roll back an odometer!")

    def increment_odometer(self, miles):
        self.odometer_reading += miles
        return('This car increase another ' + str(miles)+' mileages in this 2 months.')

my_new_car = Car('Acura', 'TSX', 2010)
my_new_car.update_odometer(20000)
my_new_car.increment_odometer(1000)    
print(my_new_car.get_descriptive_name())
print(my_new_car.read_odometer())       #until this line the program running is fine
print(my_new_car.increment_odometer())  # Problem shows up!!!!!!
```

I assigned an argument (1000) to `my_new_car.increment_odometer().` But python always telling me: missing 1 required positional argument: 'miles' while python run `print(my_new_car.increment_odometer()).`

I did pass an value 1000 to `my_new_car.increment_odometer()`   . So I thought the `print(my_new_car.increment_odometer())`would automatically looks like  `print(my_new_car.increment_odometer(1000))`. But, actually it doesn't.

`print(my_new_car.get_descriptive_name()) print(my_new_car.read_odometer())`  These two functions work fine. The python automatically assign ('Acura', 'TSX', 2010) and (20000)to the parameter. Why `my_new_car.increment_odometer(1000)`can't assign value to `print(my_new_car.increment_odometer())`

Could some experts tell me what is the problem cause such a situation to happen?

Comment: You've defined the function to take an argument: `def increment_odometer(self, miles)`. If you don't pass anything to the function with `my_new_car.increment_odometer()`, what do you expect to happen here: `self.odometer_reading += miles`?

Comment: I did pass an value to ```my_new_car.increment_odometer(1000)   ```. So I thought the ```print(my_new_car.increment_odometer())```would automatically looks like this ```print(my_new_car.increment_odometer(1000))```

Comment: No, those are two different function calls.

Comment: What is the intent of the print statement? Do you want to print the result of the first call to `increment_odometer` or do you want to increment the odometer again (that is, 2000 in total)?

Comment: ```print(my_new_car.get_descriptive_name())
print(my_new_car.read_odometer()) ``` but this two function work fine. The python automatically assign ```('Acura', 'TSX', 2010) and (20000)```to the parameter. Why ``my_new_car.increment_odometer(1000)```can assign value to ```print(my_new_car.increment_odometer())```

Comment: Did you think that `increment_odometer` would remember the last paramater you called it with and re-use it?  No, that's not how things work.

Comment: You will need to read up on methods and attributes. Calling the `.increment_odometer()` with parameter `1000` will run the method, which increments the attribute `odometer_reading` by 1000. If you want to read the current value of the odometer, you want to read that attribute, not call the method again like you are doing.

Comment: I am learning the python 'class' concept by reading 《Python Crash Course》. The above function is an example content of chapter 9.23. My intent is print a statement by using the ```my_new_car.increment_odometer(1000)```function.

Comment: @Grismar could explain more details? or write me a code to tell me what can I do to achieve my intent?

Comment: @Grismar could explain more details? What code should I write to let the function read that attribute rather than call the method? could you show me to code?

Comment: You're already calling `.read_odometer()`, which prints that value. You could easily `print(my_new_car.odometer_reading)` - but if you need someone on StackOverflow to tell you that, I strongly recommend returning to the lesson material and re-reading, or following a few tutorials on Python and Python OO basics.

Comment: @Grismar, sorry to make you confuse. I think I already found my answer.  The reason ```print(my_new_car.get_descriptive_name())
print(my_new_car.read_odometer())    ```could be printed because they have their attributes  from the other function. The ```print(my_new_car.increment_odometer())```can't be printed because it don't have its own attribute to print.  
I should pay more attention to the knowledge of function attributes. Thanks for inspiring me.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer, instead of as an edit to the question or as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print(my_new_car.increment_odometer(1000))

Comment: Try this, as you defines the function to take miles but you are not providing the value during printing

Comment: Sorry to make you guys confuse. I think I already found my answer.  The reason ```print(my_new_car.get_descriptive_name())
print(my_new_car.read_odometer())    ```could be printed because they have their attributes  from the other function. The ```print(my_new_car.increment_odometer())```can't be printed because it don't have its own attribute to print.  
I should pay more attention to the knowledge of function attributes. Thanks for inspiring me. Wish you the best

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to my question.

```
    """A simple attempt to represent a car."""

    def __init__(self, manufacturer, model, year):
        """Initialize attributes to describe a car."""
        self.manufacturer = manufacturer
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0
        self.mile=0  # add one more variable 


    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        """Return a neatly formatted descriptive name."""
        long_name = str(self.year) + ' ' + self.manufacturer + ' ' + self.model
        return long_name.title()

    def read_odometer(self):
        """Print a statement showing the car's mileage."""
        return("This car now has " + str(self.odometer_reading) + " miles on it.")

    def update_odometer(self, mileage):

        if mileage >= self.odometer_reading:
            self.odometer_reading = mileage
        else:
            print("You can't roll back an odometer!")

    def increment_odometer(self, miles):
        """Add the given amount to the odometer reading."""
        self.odometer_reading = self.odometer_reading+miles
        # set this variable as the attribute for the function of mileage_increament
        self.mile = self.mile+miles
        return('This car increase another ' + str(miles)+' mileages in this 2 months.')

    def mileage_increament(self):
        return('This car increase another ' + str(self.mile)+' mileages in this 2 months.')

my_new_car = Car('Acura', 'TSX', 2010)
my_new_car.update_odometer(20000)
my_new_car.increment_odometer(2000)

print(my_new_car.get_descriptive_name())
print(my_new_car.read_odometer())
print(my_new_car.mileage_increament()) #the attribute is come from increment_odometer(2000)
```